# Firebase Auth for Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase

I am writing an application that uses OAuth on the front end of my application using Firebase Auth. I want to then use that logged in validation for calling a backend controller on a Spring Boot app. Is there a way to ensure that:

1) User token is valid

2) Retrieve information about user via token

3) Ensure that token comes from my app?

Documentation is kind of sparse except for JavaDoc, wasn't sure if someone could provide some guidance.

Comment: Essentially I want to use Firebase as my auth server for all of my applications.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am very late to answer this.

You can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users#further_reading) to configure your spring boot application, so that your app will follow the Firebase security (i.e you have to update your app.yaml file with the security config).

And then on your client side add header as follows,
Authorization: Bearer

So if you follow the above steps then your 1 question will be addressed.

For your 2nd question you can follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) which will give the client code to access all the user details.

I am not sure about the 3rd question.